# Have any cultures had a four-element system different from fire, earth, air (or wind), and water?

Tags: ancient-greece, cultural-history, ancient-china, islamic-history, classical-japan

Ancient Greek culture (Empedocles, Aristotle) had fire, earth, air, and water. Such a system is also known in Buddhism and alchemy. Sometimes the third of these elements is conceived as wind.

Hinduism has these four plus a fifth, understood as aether or void; Japanese culture conceives of the fifth as void, sky, or heaven.

Chinese and Korean culture have five elements: fire, earth, water, wood, and metal.

My question is this: have there been any human cultures that have had a four-element system different from fire-earth-air(wind)-water?

Comment: Google says [Norse](https://www.terriwindling.com/blog/2015/03/elemental-magic.html) - not sure how reliable that is (hence comment vice answer), but a starting point for further research.